# Swift NSInvalidArgumentException while switching views programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using this Swift code to switch views programmatically:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let message = messageArray[indexPath.row]
    print ("messageClickAction executed. MessageID " + message.getMessageID())

    let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewMessage")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
}
```

This exception is thrown:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView _setRefreshControl:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13fdc6e20'

ViewMessageController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewMessageController : UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var messageSender: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var messageTimestamp: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var messageContent: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    print ("View loaded.")
 }
}
```

Any idea how to fix this exception? Thanks!

Comment: None of this code causes the error. The message clearly says that somewhere a selector `_setRefreshControl` with one parameter is called which does not exist in the receiver.

Comment: Where should I add _setRefreshControl? ViewMessageController?

Comment: Most likely in the class the error occurs.

Comment: Added the method, error still occurs. func setRefreshControl() {
        
    } is all that was added.

Comment: First of all the error says it's something with a leading underscore and taking a parameter (the `:`) and second of all find out where the message is sent.

Comment: When the error occurs, XCode opens the AppDelegate file and highlights the class. I've also added the underscore to the setRefreshControl function, but am unsure what parameters it requires

Comment: Set the exception breakpoint to get the exact location of the exception or use the search function (⇧⌘F) to search for the function (I suspect it's the implicit setter of a property `refreshControl`)

Comment: The entire method used for detecting a cell click action is fine (Checked w/ breakpoint), and I can't find a setter for a refreshControl property.